# What folders are commonly used by version control systems?

Tags: directory, version-control

I need to know what folder names are commonly used by Version Control systems.  Many VCSs will create a hidden folder, usually in the top level of the source tree, to store the information that they use.

So far, I only know that Git uses `.git/` and SVN uses `.svn/`.

What are the folder names that other popular VCSs use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could probably divide the VCSs into three groups:

*Special Subdirectory in each directory*

- CVS
- Subversion (.svn)

The advantage of this is that each directory in the working copy is a self-contained working copy: you can copy it out somewhere else and it will still work.  The obvious disadvantage is the clutter.  Using automatic tools to scan over one of these working copies need special filtering or they will return spurious results.

*Single special directory for each working copy*

- Mercurial (.hg)
- SVK
- (Maybe Git, I'm not sure?)

*Special file system support*

- ClearCase (dynamic view is a mounted FS; snapshot view is more similar to the single directory case)

Comment: It doesn't really matter to me exactly what the layout is - I'm just using a regular expression on the filename to filter out all those that have the VCS directory in the path - that seems like it should do for what I need

Answer (score 1):

Mercurial = a single `.hg` directory